# Prove that $x^2+(x+1)^2+(x+2)^2=y^2$ has no integer solutions

Tags: polynomials

I have tried to expand this into $3x^2+6x+5 = y^2$. What do I do now?

I’m assuming something to do with integers modulo $n$ but what would that have to do with solving $y= \sqrt{3x^2+6x+5}$?

The chapter is on ring theory but what does this have to do with “$\mathbb{Z}_n$ as a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}$”?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4):

After expanding, take both sides modulo 3. The result should be immediately obvious.

Comment: There are only $2$ cases to check ($0, ±1)$ mod 3.

Comment: So it would be x²+2 = y²?

Comment: Yep, and there are no squares congruent to $2$ modulo $3$.

Comment: Why do you do modulo 3 and not say 4, or 7?
What’s modulo n got to do with it and how does this question apply to ring theory (I’m new to ring theory sorry if I’m being stupid)

Comment: The $3$ and $6$ in $3x^2+6x+5$ are divisible by $3$. Mod $8$ also works according to [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1068820h2497043p21052126).

Comment: Don't worry, I don't know any ring theory. This is elementary number theory, so you should go back and revise that section.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve studied modular arithmetic & number theory before but I don’t think we used it for solving polynomials.

Comment: Don't worry! Don't let this question put you off as problem-solving is much more than a bag of tricks. I hope your studies in ring theory go smoothly ;)

Comment: Thank you! We have a group theory module that I did at uni so I figured I'd expand my knowledge and found ring theory in a textbook my lecturer told me about :)
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Apply the canonical quotient homomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$$ to your equality to obtain
$$2 = y^2.$$
This is impossible in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, as the only squares in this ring are $0^2 = 0, 1^2 = 1$ and $2^2 = 1.$

Comment: I suspect that this answer uses a term or four that the poster isn't familiar with.